# Distributing task with python and zeromq

Tags: python, distributed, zeromq

I have a working application using python and zeromq and I would like to optimize it.

Briefly, a master node send the same request to all workers (about 200) and the then collect the answers. Based on the answer, it sends a message back to one node and the node answers back.

Right now I implemented a very simple pattern. Each worker has one REP socket and the server has a list of REQ sockets. The server iterates through all sockets sending the general message and then iterates through all sockets to collect the answers. Finally, based on the answers the server picks one worker, sends a message to it and waits for the reply.

This is, of course, quite slow. The slowest part is sending 200 times the same message. Collecting is also slow. The solutions that I have found to distribute tasks and collect answers do load balance which is not what I need. I need that each worker receives the message and responds.

What is the pattern recommended for this situation?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean "What is the pattern recommended for this situation?"

Comment: For example, if you have to process independent tasks, you can use the ventilator pattern to distribute the task as described here http://taotetek.wordpress.com/2011/02/02/python-multiprocessing-with-zeromq/

Comment: I know what a pattern is. You haven't actually explained what you are doing, what parts of your current solution are required, or even why distributing your messages is slow. The classic solution for "distributing things is slow" is to not distribute things, or do less of it.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me think the problem again but please give some credit. I need to distribute because the workers need to access information which does not fit in the RAM of one node (and accessing the disk is to slow). Distributing the messagetakes two orders of magnitude longer that the round trip to each node. That makes sense as I am doing it 200 times. That round trip includes all the overhead of going through the network stack. I was wondering if there was a pattern batches all this calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know zmq. Here's a pattern that might not work, just to get started:

> a master node send the same request to all workers (about 200)

master PUB bind *:3140 send

worker SUB connect masterhost:3140 SUBSCRIBE recv

> the then collect the answers

worker PUSH connect masterhost:3141 send

master PULL bind *:3141 recv

> Based on the answer, it sends a message back to one node and the node answers back.

master REQ connect workerhost:3142 send recv

worker REP bind *:3142 recv send

Comment: I finally had some time to implement and test this. The first part (distributing the same task) is 100 times faster as I am distributing using pub/sub instead of looping through 200 sockets. The second part (collecting the answers) is still quit slow (takes 8 ms). What I am doing is calling recv 200 times in the pull socket. Is there a way to tell zeromq: "wait for 200 messages and return them as an array when ready"?

Comment: Why would  "wait for 200 messages and return them as an array when ready" be faster than what you are already doing?  Unless there is something else slowing you down I think it would be only faster if you used many threads to pull the messages, which you could try.

Comment: @AaronWatters: 0MQ Sockets are *not* threadsafe. **DO NOT** share them across threads.

Comment: @Hernan: 25k messages per seconds doesn't sound bad for a generic PULL socket. How do you get `8 ms` number? You could try to tweak socket, OS network options. Calling a dummy function 200 times takes ~1 microsecond in Python. `.recv()` releases/reacquires GIL so it *might* contribute to the delay.

Answer (score 2):

If each worker should need a different job, Pub/sub wont work . What you need then is a worker pool Implementation. Either you push out the jobs in a round robin style (just use the push socket bound on the server and have each client pull from it, zeromq will do the round robin) or you have each worker request a job from the server, if the jobs are at least of some minimum complexity and the variance between jobs is high that is a better approach. There are numerous examples in the zeromq guide on its homepage and on the net:

- http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all (look at the paronoid pirate pattern)
- http://blog.garambrogne.net/post/2010/10/23/simple-python-work-queue-with-zeromq
- https://github.com/marklit/zeromq-worker-queue

The concrete implementation also depends on whether or not you need to have jobs reliably processed.

Comment: Thanks but as described in my question, each worker does the same thing (but in their own part of the data).